# Getting an unkwon traceback with .json project?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm

I am currently making my first project with AI. I am making a basic chatbot and am trying to import my .json file with my intents, however am getting some error.

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
docuements = []
ignore_letters = ['?','!', '.', ',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.append(word_list)
        docuements.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

print(docuements)
```

and this is the traceback I am getting

```
C:\Users\id4am\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/id4am/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/training.py
2021-02-19 01:53:52.558317: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/id4am/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/training.py", line 15, in <module>
    intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())
  File "C:\Users\id4am\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\id4am\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\id4am\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 85 (char 123)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, when i get this error:

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 85 (char 123)`

its because the json `syntax` is **wrong**.

so take a look at your JSON file and find the `syntax error`.

or show me the JSON file, if its not confidential.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `intents.json` file if there are any errors in the delimiter, and compare the `ignore_letters` in the code. It may be that these two places are not uniform.